# MATLAB - Importing a GPS-indexed satellite image

Tags: matlab, gps, mapping, wms

I'm fairly new to programming, I'm working in Matlab R2012b.  I do have the mapping toolbox.

I've got some GPS data from a GPS logger of some local trails that I'm looking to log on a satellite map.  I'm currently not sure where to obtain said map, how to import it, etc.

My goal is to find and import a satellite image and then plot the GPS coordinates on the image corresponding to their actual location so that the trails are accurately showing up on the satellite image.

I had attempted using the WMS approach listed in the tutorial, however the WMS servers don't seem to be currently accessible.

I can currently manage to read and plot the GPS data points fine, it's getting the satellite image underlay that's causing me extensive grief.

Any help or direction that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: I'm not sure which tutorial you're following. Perhaps [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/examples/creating-map-displays-with-latitude-and-longitude-data.html) might be more useful?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you want to solve? As it's asked your question is too broad.
Also, keep in mind that questions asking us to recommend a book or tutorial are considered off topic and are likely to be closed.